# installing from .run

Tags: software-installation

Today I have downloaded Metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run.
I have clicked the icon to install only to be greeted with the error message:

```
Could not display "/home/daniel/Downloads/metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run".
There is no application installed for executable files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

Upon clicking yes the results of the search only show one application.
This application is called "Pypar2".
(a graphical interface for the Par2 utility)

I hesitantly click install only to be told further python support is required and i click install for that also.
Window pops up ......Installing packages....done

Pypar2 also installs and I open.

This doesn't seem right this seems to be a program to verify the contents? I don't know what i am doing wrong this is on my second day using ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Daniel! Here's what you need to do:

1. Open a terminal. To do so, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type `cd /home/daniel/Downloads/`. This command will go to that folder (i.e. change our working directory to that folder).
3. Type `sudo chmod +x metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run`. Enter your password when asked. This command makes the file executable, so that you can "install" it.
4. Type `sudo ./metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run`. This command will run the file.

Wait a bit, and you should see the Metasploit screen come up and continue with the installation.

**EDIT**: thanks to [Leopoldo Pla's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/303902/52726):

Once the installation is done, you can update metasploit using the command `sudo msfupdate`...this can take some time though. Once it's done, you can fire up the metsploit framework console using the command `sudo msfconsole`.

Enjoy the exploiting!

Comment: perfect ... bang on the money thankyou :)

Comment: You're welcome! I've edited the answer to include the last two commands from Leopoldo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To execute that .run program, you have to open a Terminal and write:

```
cd Downloads

chmod +x metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run
```

Then:

```
sudo ./metasploit-latest-linux-installer.run
```

And after installed, update before executing:

```
sudo msfupdate
```

And execute:

```
msfconsole
```